# How can I use assertion on type of currency

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I want to put assertion on type of currency (eg: USD, CAD .. ) right now I'm hardcoding the values and check against the response I got from the application. I can do it with XML file where I can put all the currency type and check against it but It will but too much coding for just one line of assertion I need my automation work.

> Let me show you the approach I have taken.. in below mention code

```
getSourceCurrName = getDriver().findElement(by("label.source_curr_type")).getText();
AssertUtil.assertTrue("Validate source currency type",(getSourceCurrName.equalsIgnoreCase("CAD") || getSourceCurrName.equalsIgnoreCase("USD"));
```

As I said I can do by keeping all the currencies name into xml n use those values instead of hardcoding USD and CAD in function. But that would be lengthy process is there anything java offers ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with ISO 4217 Currency Codes, java has a Currency class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) where you can get all currency codes as a set.